# Why are active filters preferred over passive filters?

Tags: operational-amplifier, passive-networks, active-filter, passive-filter

This question was asked to me in an interview. I replied that passive and active filters both have their merits and demerits :

1. Unlike passive, active filters provide mechanism for gain adjustment
2. Passive filters are easy to construct and relatively inexpensive

However, the interviewer seemed not interested in "trade offs" but only "why are active filters preferred over passive filters" ?

Please elaborate on this. Thanks

Comment: Passive filter causes an attenuation of signal. So in case when more fillers are connected in series the output signal decreases rapidly in aplitude.  Active filters avoid this attenuation.

Comment: If I had to guess this is going to be about constructing 2nd order filters without heavy and expensive inductors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Passive and active filters each have their domain of superiority. If the interviewer thought that one was definitely 'better', he must have been operating in one of those domains (is the charitable explanation).

Active filters do not need inductors, they can be synthesised with feedback and Rs and Cs. At audio frequencies where inductors can be large and difficult to source, that's a big bonus. Active filters can use adjustable resistors, so can be tunable over wide ranges.

However, passive filters are quieter, can carry power currents (taking either of those, and especially both together, that means having a better dynamic range), and are the only option at RF and GHz frequencies.

If you want to confront an interviewer's mindset, then 'tradeoffs' is maybe a bit lame, and you need to demonstrate your understanding and go more into the detail of when either are better.

There is a historical context as well. While the adjustment range of active filters did used to be important, there are not many signal chains these days that don't involve a digital section, and digital filters are far more flexible, adjustable, and stable than active filters can ever be. That can relegate real filters to the anti-alias filters around ADC/DACs, whether active or passive.

Comment: Are you saying that at RF and GHz frequencies, active filters cannot be used ? If yes then please provide explanation. I feel thay active filters should work fine at all frequencies whereas passive filters will need an inductor at higher frequencies, thereby making them bulkier.

Comment: @MAJIDAHMAD Passive filters of order 2 or higher need an inductor at all frequencies, not just high frequencies. Inductors tend to be smaller and less bulky at high frequencies. Opamps, needed for active filters, become less common as frequencies rise. If you want a MHz active filter, you need a GHz GBW active devices. If you want a GHz active filter, you need THz active devices, and they aren't available, whereas small inductors are. You've failed my interview on many counts.

Answer (score 1):

I think, the most important aspect is that active filters do not need inductors in form of coils. This is because mechanical coils

- have weight and volume
- are hard to tune
- are problematic for monolithic integration
- are sensible to EMC (receive and transmit electromagnic signals)
- are sensible to mechanical stress.

More than that, passive filters are extremely sensitive to external loads. Therefore, they require an amplifier anyway, which can then also be designed as an active filter at the same time.

Note that pure RC filters (without active elements) are only able to produce Q-values below 0.5